# Срабатывает другое событие при клике на кнопку

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть конструкция:

```
<tr class="example1"> 
  <a class="example2"></a>
</tr>
```

В обработчике для него написано:

```
$('.example1').click(...); 
//Событие, если нажимаем на  строку таблицы
```

Еще есть событие на кнопке по тому же принципу:

```
$('.example2').click(...); 
//Событие, если нажимаем на  кнопку внутри строки таблицы
```

Проблема в том, что когда я нажимаю на кнопку `example2`, то срабатывает и событие для всей строки. Т.е. `example1`.

Как то можно этого избежать?

Comment: Проблема решена.

`stopPropagation();`

Answer (score 1):

Все дело в том что клик по тегу `anchor` "всплывает" наверх, что бы это предотвратить можно воспользоваться методом [stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation):

```js
const handleDivClick = event => {
  console.log("Click on DIV")
}

const handleAnchorClick = event => {
  event.stopPropagation()
  console.log("Click on ANCHOR")
}

$("div").on("click", handleDivClick)
$("a").on("click", handleAnchorClick)
```

```css
.div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: red;
}

.div > a {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: pink;
  padding: 10px 15px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div">
  <a>Anchor</a>
</div>
```